# What is a safe way to send Wordpress Username info over to another website?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, security, cross-site

I have a web application (let's just refer to its address as 'xyz.com' for security purposes) that I want to be accessible only to users of a WordPress website. In the WP site, the logged in user can click a button that opens 'xyz.com' in a seperate tab. xyz.com is a Node.js application, created via MeteorJS, so it has both a client side and script and a server side script, but no PHP.

I want to make it so that accessing xyz.com will be denied, or at least limited, if the user directly goes to it without first logging in through the Wordpress site and accessing it via the button. I'm trying to figure out a relatively secure way to do this. I would also like to be able to distinguish between each username, as this is needed for a feature in the application.

The method I was considering is to place the button in a form that gets the current logged in Username, then send the username through $_POST data when you click the link, which then checks to see if there is a username in the $_POST data (via XMLHttpRequest or something similar), and what the name is.
However, I'm not sure how secure that would be, as the code is mostly client side, meaning couldn't someone look at the code and determine that they simply need to send a username through a $_POST data form? Is there a way to authenticate that the data is coming from the Wordpress site? Am I just overthinking this and this is an unlikely scenario for a simple website to be attacked like such?

Comment: *Am I just overthinking this and this is an unlikely scenario for a simple website to be attacked like such?* IMO yes - 99.9% of normal users would authenticate through the process you want them to. There might be 0.1% of users who are web developers and know and care enough to bypass it, but that's probably not worth worrying about, unless, eg, the site gets popular enough such that a third-party app to bypass your verification would be possible.

Comment: For many apps, a *foolproof method* to get around possible client-side tampering isn't possible. "Close enough" is a whole lot easier to achieve.